Negative average marginal effect for positive estimate in ordinal logistic regression
I'm running an ordinal logistic regression with eight indepdent variables and the dependent variable has five categories (1 = Not at all and 5 = To a great extent). To interpret the coefficient estimates I want to estimate average marginal effects, but when I estimate the positive estimates from the regression result in negative average marginal effects. I don't understand why this happens and I have not managed to find an explanation. Does anyone have suggestions for why this occurs?
I ran the regression using the polr function in the MASS package and estimated the average marginal effects using the margins function in the margins package.
library(MASS)

mod <- polr(dv ~ gender_num + permanent + position + Discipline + approved + decisionyear_fac + age2cat + institution_other, data = data)
    
Coefficients:
                                                                   Value Std. Error  t 
value
gender_num                                                          0.157040     0.1464  1.07283
permanent                                                           0.071750     0.1758  0.40815
position                                                            0.126786     0.1676  0.75631
Discipline2                                                        -0.230337     0.1795 -1.28300
Discipline3                                                         0.046918     0.1669  0.28113
approved                                                            0.527170     0.1533  3.43890
decisionyear_fac2020                                                0.004765     0.1420  0.03356
age2cat                                                            -0.127205     0.1496 -0.85004
institution_other2                                                  0.015838     0.1824  0.08683
institution_other3                                                 -0.131945     0.2104 -0.62716
institution_other4                                                  0.243368     0.2979  0.81705

Intercepts:
    Value    Std. Error t value 
1|2  -3.6311   0.2863   -12.6848
2|3  -2.5609   0.2197   -11.6573
3|4  -1.4832   0.1920    -7.7246
4|5   0.1783   0.1830     0.9745

Residual Deviance: 1944.782 
AIC: 1974.782 
(20 observations deleted due to missingness)


library(margins)

mod_ame <- margins(mod)
summary(mod_ame)

factor                       AME     SE       z      p   lower   upper
age2cat                    0.0028 0.0034  0.8060 0.4202 -0.0040  0.0095
approved                  -0.0115 0.0031 -3.7614 0.0002 -0.0175 -0.0055
decisionyear_fac2020      -0.0001 0.0031 -0.0336 0.9732 -0.0062  0.0060
gender_num                -0.0034 0.0031 -1.1171 0.2640 -0.0094  0.0026
institution_other2        -0.0003 0.0039 -0.0874 0.9304 -0.0080  0.0073
institution_other3         0.0030 0.0050  0.6034 0.5462 -0.0068  0.0129
institution_other4        -0.0047 0.0052 -0.8970 0.3697 -0.0150  0.0056 
Discipline2                0.0053 0.0046  1.1524 0.2491 -0.0037  0.0143
Discipline3               -0.0009 0.0033 -0.2863 0.7746 -0.0074  0.0055
position                  -0.0028 0.0036 -0.7703 0.4411 -0.0098  0.0043
permanent                 -0.0016 0.0038 -0.4076 0.6836 -0.0091  0.0060



I believe there's a bug in the margins package in its handling of categorical outcome models. You might want to try the marginaleffects package instead, with the avg_slopes(mod_ame) command.

It's displaying the AME only for the first category; there should be five AMEs.
